# How does major website checks for user authentication?

Tags: php, mysql, server

As the title, I ask this question because the only way I know how to check if a user is logged in, is by having on top of each file a session and a query to data base to compared the sessions value.

I have something like this function, then I call this function on top of every php file, this works fine. However I dont think big website such as facebook, youtube and so on has this approach, also this means that all my files have to be `.php` I cant have `.html` as I wouldn't be able to run the function below.

```
public function isSessionValid()
{
    session_start();
    $dbConfig = new dbconfig("users");
    $dbUser = $dbConfig->getDbUser();
    $getUser = new GetUser($dbUser);
    $result = $getUser->getUser($_SESSION['UN'],$_SESSION['PW'] );
    if(!count($result) > 0){
        header("Location: ../index.html");
    }
}
```

My question is what are other efficient ways of checking for users credentials?

Comment: Can you explain that further? What makes you think that other pages **don't** work like that? Additionally, only because a URL ends in `.html` does not mean it is not served by PHP (or another server-side language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to have something like:

> $_SESSION['PW']

Plain text unencrypted passwords are a serious concern. You could do something where upon login, you create a access token that is a random hashed string and that gets saved to the users cookies.

Here's an example:

```
function login()
{
    $userName = 'billy';
    $password = 'foobar';

    // get your user data using username and password.
    $userObject = new User();
    $userId = $userObject->id;

    // create our secure hash.
    $accessToken = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    // update the user in the row.
    mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users set access_token='$accessToken' WHERE id = $userId");

    // expires in 1 day, auto logout.
    setcookie('userAccessToken', $accessToken, time() + 86400);
}

function getUser() {
    return mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from users WHERE access_token = ".$_COOKIE['userAccessToken']);
}
```

Now you only need to check for one attribute which is the access token, and its stored in the cookies in case they come back. Using the hash approach prevents anyone sniffing the cookies and getting private information.

For code maintainability you don't want duplicate code and should always try to create small reusable components that can be used across all your pages. Make a PHP file called auth.php and then just require it in the pages where you need it.

```
// UserPage.php
require_once __DIR__.'/lib/auth.php';

$user = getUser();

// MessagePage.php
require_once __DIR__.'/lib/auth.php';

$user = getUser();

// lib/auth.php
function getUser() {
   return mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from users WHERE access_token = ".$_COOKIE['userAccessToken']);
}
```

As a side note, rather than writing your application in plain php and building your own framework, I recommend you checkout [laravel.com](https://laravel.com). They have video tutorials and the framework solves a lot of common problems developers run into, including this one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the security issues im running myself into.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to configure the webserver to automatically route all requests through `isSessionValid()` first, then to their actual destination.

Comment: thanks that sounds exactly what I want. not sure why someone downvote, is something wrong with the answer?